# how to tell the difference between length(name) and length('abc ') in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql version 5.6.
I got confused by the usage of length(name) and length('abc   ') in mysql. When I tried this:

```
CREATE TABLE char_test(name char(5));
INSERT INTO CHAR_TEST 
VALUES('ABC  ');

SELECT LENGTH(NAME) FROM char_test;
```

The result I got is 3;

But if i just do this:

`SELECT LENGTH('ABC   ')`,

or

`SELECT CHAR_LENGTH('ABC   ')`

the result is 6.

Can anyone tell me why it is 3 in the first case, and 6 in the second? 
Thank you!

Comment: Search for "ANSI padding" - trailing spaces are effectively ignored in non-variable width column types. Change your column type to `varchar(5)`.

Comment: But since the char(3) type fix the character length to 3, why the length() function doesn't give the fixed length which is 3 in this case?

Comment: I don't understand your question, sorry. Please reword it.